# Handle android rotate screen

Tags: android, kotlin, rotation, landscape

How to handle android rotate screen if I have a fragment that observe the data from view model to fill recyclerview list ?!
when rotation happened the data lost, so how can I handle it with viewmodel so the user didn't feel any different after rotation?

this is the part of the view model the return data:

```
 private fun getImageList(keyWord: String) {
        responseManager.loading()
        val disposable = imageListUseCase.execute(keyWord, { success ->
            responseManager.hideLoading()
            _observeImageListData.value = Event(success)
        }, { error ->
            responseManager.failed(error)
        })

        compositeDisposable.add(disposable)
    }
```

and here I set the recycler data on the fragment:

**UPDATE**

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class ImagePickerFragment : Fragment() {

    private lateinit var imagePickerBinding: FragmentImagePickerBinding
    private val imagePickerViewModel: ImagePickerViewModel by activityViewModels()
    private lateinit var imagePickerAdapter: ImagePickerAdapter

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {

        imagePickerBinding = FragmentImagePickerBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        observeImageList()
        observeSearchText()

        return imagePickerBinding.root
    }


    private fun observeImageList() {
        imagePickerViewModel.observeImageListData.observe(
            viewLifecycleOwner,
            EventObserver { imageList ->
                imagePickerAdapter = ImagePickerAdapter(imageList, imagePickerViewModel)
                imagePickerBinding.apply {
                    rvImageList.setHasFixedSize(true)
                    rvImageList.layoutManager = GridLayoutManager(requireContext(),2)
                    rvImageList.adapter = imagePickerAdapter
                }
            })
    }
```

Any tips?

**UPDATE :**

The viewModel extends from BaseViewModel :

```
abstract class BaseViewModel: ViewModel() {

    val compositeDisposable = CompositeDisposable()

    override fun onCleared() {
        super.onCleared()
        compositeDisposable.clear()
    }
}
```

and this is the full viewmodel:

```
@HiltViewModel
class ImagePickerViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val imageListUseCase: ImageListUseCase,
    private val responseManager: ResponseManager
) : BaseViewModel() {

    private val _observeImageListData = MutableLiveData<Event<ArrayList<Image>>>()


    init {
        getImageList(Constants.KEY_WORD)
    }


    private fun getImageList(keyWord: String) {
        responseManager.loading()
        val disposable = imageListUseCase.execute(keyWord, { success ->
            responseManager.hideLoading()
            _observeImageListData.value = Event(success)
        }, { error ->
            responseManager.failed(error)
        })

        compositeDisposable.add(disposable)
    }

    fun filterSearchKeyWord(filteredKeyWord: String) {
        if(filteredKeyWord.isNotEmpty())
            getImageList(filteredKeyWord)
    }

    //getters:
    val observeImageListData: LiveData<Event<ArrayList<Image>>>
        get() = _observeImageListData
}
```

Comment: This should work. I think we need to see more of your ViewModel to understand what’s going wrong with it.

Comment: Updated, check it please

Comment: I still can't find an error. Can you show the code where you instantiate the ViewModel in the fragment?

Comment: Updated, And I I'm sorry for the inconvenience and thank you for your help :)

Answer (score -1):

In your manifest, try putting this in your activity tag:

```
android:configChanges="orientation"
```

So it looks like:

```
       <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation"
        android:exported="true">
```

Comment: This solution is highly discouraged in the official documentation because it leaves you to deal with manually modifying any view that needs its resources reloaded.